# Printing arrays messes everything

Tags: python

I am beginner in python and want to ask about my code. My code:-

```
indexes = ["COMMANDS"]
indexvalues = ["USAGE"]
def index(c, u):
    indexes.append(c)
    indexvalues.append(u)
index("printer", "A simple text Printer")
print(indexes)
print(indexvalues)
for index in range(len(indexes)):
        indexn = indexes[index]
        for indexvalue in range(len(indexvalues)):
            print("\t \t \t" + indexes[index] + "\t \t \t \t \t \t" + indexvalues[indexvalue] + "\n \n")
```

But when I run this in cmd, it produces the following output:-

```
COMMANDS                                                USAGE


                        COMMANDS                                                A simple text Printer


                        printer                                         USAGE


                        printer                                         A simple text Printer
```

Printing the whole array doesn't shows this. How can I fix it?

Comment: you are using \t and \n, that's why its giving such an output

Comment: The output is same but without tabs spaces, I wan only the first and last output and I haven't called the in between text.

Comment: Please put  your desired output in the question, it will be easy for me to understand and help

Comment: The output is that I only want the text I have told to print once, but it is mixing both variables in the between lines of the real output.

Answer (score 0):

Too messy with `\t` which is tab and `\n` which is newline accordingly.